# Reply, with template, using properties of original mail

Tags: vba, email, templates, outlook

I work at a Company that gets requests we filter in terms of

- being eligibile for financing from our financing partner
- requiring more information from the enquirer

There is a lot of monotonous work, in copy pasting email replies.

I looked into creating a Quick Action in Outlook, but because our mother company does not allow certain freedoms, like the Font has to be specifically Segoe Ui Light etc. I could not use this, so I thought about writing a macro.

I intended for a macro button to:

Open a new Reply email, replying to all in the original mail.

In this new email text body, use a template email that I already made and saved as a template. (This way it saved the Font, size and other formatting.)

Put in the original Sender and CC'ed mail addresses as well as the Subject from the original mail.

And then display the email, so I could make edits if I wanted to before sending.

```vb
Sub ReplyGewerbeanmeldung()

    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem

    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Item(1)
    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(" "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\ReplyGewerbeanmeldung.oft"\ReplyGewerbeanmeldung.oft")

    replyEmail.To = origEmail.Sender
    replyEmail.CC = origEmail.CC
    replyEmail.Subject = origEmail.Subject
    
    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.Display
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems you need to correct the file path to the template message. The following string is not a valid file path:

```
" "C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\ReplyGewerbeanmeldung.oft"\ReplyGewerbeanmeldung.oft"
```

Try to use the following string instead:

```
 Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\ReplyGewerbeanmeldung.oft")
```

You can read more about that in the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article.

Anyway, creating items from a template will not preserve the original message body. Moreover, in Outlook you will not get any visual appearance that a particular items was replied. So, you need to call the `ReplyAll` method on the original item in Outlook to avoid this artefacts in Outlook.

You can create a new mail item, but only for copying the message body response which is required to paste into the reply. The [NameSpace.OpenSharedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.openshareditem) method can be used to to open iCalendar appointment (.ics) files, vCard (.vcf) files, and Outlook message (.msg) files. You may consider using it instead of creating a new item based on the template to grab the message body from there.